# Categories Not Showing When there's 1 Post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having an odd issue at the moment.

I just posted my first blog post on my WordPRess blog and for some reason,the category list isn't showing.

I posted another post to test it out and then the categories began to show for BOTH posts. So I thought a miracle had happend.

So, I deleted the test post (going back to one post), and then the issue began again.No category list.

I'm stumped because the code seems to be sound and why would posting another post make the category list work?

You can click [here]{http://www.noellesnotes.com} to visit the site and see the issue I'm having.

I think I found the issue. It's in this code below:

```
<?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $category_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'ribbons-and-clouds' ) );

            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'ribbons-and-clouds' ) );

            if ( ! ribbons_and_clouds_categorized_blog() ) {
                // This blog only has 1 category so we just need to worry about tags in the meta text
                if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ribbons-and-clouds' );
                } else {
                    $meta_text = __( 'Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ribbons-and-clouds' );
                }

            } else {
                // But this blog has loads of categories so we should probably display them here
                if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ribbons-and-clouds' );
                } else {
                    $meta_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'ribbons-and-clouds' );
                }

            } // end check for categories on this blog

            printf(
                $meta_text,
                $category_list,
                $tag_list,
                get_permalink(),
                the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' )
            );
        ?>
```

See how one of the if statements tells it not to list the categories if there's only one?

Does anyone know how to edit this code to make the categories display no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine, maybe a theme problem? try with another theme and see if it will work

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a theme issue because it doesn't happen on other themes, but I just don't know what could be causing the issue...